# DEBUG does not work on all executables?

Tags: debugging, assembly, codeblocks

I have Windows 7 installed on my PC. I am learning C and assembly language together. I use codeblock IDE for writing C codes and emu8086 for assembly codes. I am able to DEBUG the assembly codes from DOS prompt, but not the C codes. Why so? 
I select console application option while writing C codes. they run well on their own from DOS prompt, but not through DEBUG mode. 
I intend to observe the machine code and the symbolic assembly code created by the C compiler. 
I was assuming that Using DEBUG  I should be able to trace the execution of all executable files, after all that is the purpose of DEBUG. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to download Microsoft's [Debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) and use Windbg (or the debugger that undoubtedly came with whatever compiler you're using).

Answer (score 1):

If a program is not compiled with debug symbols (virtually every program is not), you will not see c or other source code when debugging it. You will only see the lowest level, and that is assembly.